# Colspan spanning 2.5 columns?

Tags: html

I have a table with 5 columns. The final row should have two cells, spaced equally.

Ideally, I would like to use `<td colspan="2.5">` - whats the most elegant way to do this?

The table has a border of 1, so using

```
<td colspan=2">abc</td>
<td></td>
<td colspan=2">def</td>
```

looks ugly

Comment: how its complicated to change to divs base design, instead of tables

Comment: +1 a valid point, although this is only a small sunset of something that cries "table" to me, I will still reconsider it. Thanks

Comment: Why didn't I make it 10 columns & double everything? D'oh !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you really need two table cells in the bottom row or just two blocks that are half the width of the entire row? If the latter, then you can make a `<td colspan="5">` for the final row, put two `<div>`s in it, float one to the left and the other to the right, and give them `width:50%`:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>2222</td>
            <td>3333</td>
            <td>4444</td>
            <td>5555</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div class="first-half">
                    half
                </div>
                <div class="second-half">
                    half
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And some CSS:

```
.first-half {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.second-half {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And the usual jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mmZEa/

If you do need them to be table cells then you could double the number of horizontal cells, make all the existing ones `<td colspan="2">`, and then use `<td colspan="5" width="50%">` for the two cells in the bottom row: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JzrLK/

Comment: Ok, I'll award the answer. But I admit I would have preferred not to float hard left & right, but to have put them with some space on each side too

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: You can toss a `<span>` inside the floaters to simulate padding without messing up the 50% (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mmZEa/1/) or put some padding on the `<td>s` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mmZEa/2/).

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: Adding `<span>`s is a bit of a hack), putting some padding on the `<td>` is cleaner and makes for prettier HTML. OTOH, you do what you gotta' do to make it go.

Comment: +1 to both of you. Yes, I will add some padding, rather than use <span>

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: Cheers. Check the padding approach in the browsers you care about, some of them may screw it up, keep the span-hack as a backup.

Answer (score 20):

Try something like this

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td colspan="2">text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td colspan="2">text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td colspan="2">text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">text</td>
        <td colspan="3">text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Worked okay on Chrome, FireFox, and IE 7-9.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/weyy601z/

Comment: +1 For the good old table design! :-) While these things become quite unreadable, they're the way to go...

Comment: hmm, sneaky (+1) So what's the lowest common denominator? Ok, if I make each 'normal' cell have a colspan of 2 and the bottom 2 have a colspan of 5, it should work. I'll try that

Comment: @LeonixSolutions : Yes, that should work. But the above code works too, and is cleaner than adding a colspan on all tds.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work nicely (tested in chrome, ie and firefox) :

```
<table border="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>abcsss</td>
                <td>sdf</td>
                <td>def</td>
                <td>def</td>
                <td>defsssss</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">test</td>
                <td width="50%">test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A nice idea, but ... 1) I don't want my table to be 100% or even any %, I want it to be as wide as it needs to be, with dynamic content, and, 2) that <td width="50%"> sets the table cell to 50% of the width of the page, not of the table.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions fixed. Forgot to surround my inner tables with td tags. That confused the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**you can simply double everything.**

instead of

> having a table with 5 columns and you would like to use `<td colspan="2.5">`

you can

> have a table with 10 columns and you would like to use `<td colspan="5">`